# Show content on hover of two elements

Tags: javascript

So I have a menu which on hover shows a container with all links to the pages. I used javascript to make it visible on hover of the menu items. It looks like this:

[image: Menu image]

On hover of the menu items it looks like this

[image: Image 2]

The problem is when I move my mouse to the container to click a link it goes to display: none again.

This is my javascript code:

```
    var topbestemmingen =  document.getElementById('menu-topbestemmingen');

    document.querySelectorAll('#menu-link-topbestemmingen').forEach(el => 
    el.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        topbestemmingen.classList.add('active');
    }))

    document.querySelectorAll('#menu-link-topbestemmingen').forEach(el => 
    el.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        topbestemmingen.classList.remove('active');
    }))
```

So the container has ID #menu-topbestemmingen and the link's in the menu #menu-link-topbestemmingen. Does anyone know how to select the container to also show on hover?

Comment: Please share this problem in an online platform to understand more clearly. Can you share your code in https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You should not use the ID attribute more than once. Instead, you can use custom attributes, e.g. `data-menu-topbestemmingen`.

Comment: Well sounds like the sub menu is not inside of the item you are hovering so mouseout is fired. So need a way to tell the code the mouse is over the sub element. Normally done with more event listeners.

Comment: Please create a [MRE] _within_ your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding mouseover -> activate to the #menu-topbestemmingen and deactivate for mouseout. So, there should be four event listeners.

but I suggest adding a layer under link menu, and menu and then add event listener to that layer for close menu.

```js
var topbestemmingen = document.getElementById('menu-topbestemmingen');

document.querySelectorAll('#menu-link-topbestemmingen').forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    topbestemmingen.style.display = 'block'

  }))
document.querySelectorAll('#menu-link-topbestemmingen').forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    topbestemmingen.style.display = 'none'

  }))
document.querySelectorAll('#menu-topbestemmingen').forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    topbestemmingen.style.display = 'block'

  }))
document.querySelectorAll('#menu-topbestemmingen').forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    topbestemmingen.style.display = 'none'

  }))
```

```css
 #menu-topbestemmingen {
   display: none;

 }
```

```html
<div id='menu-link-topbestemmingen'>
  link menu item
</div>

<div id='menu-topbestemmingen'>
  <div>
    item1
  </div>
  <div>
    item2
  </div>
  <div>
    item3
  </div>
  <div>
    item4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was thinking there would/should be a "cleaner/better" way, but this also works perfectly. Will use it like this, thanks!